# scipy: Evaluate the most likely value and confidence of a bayesian network

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a bayesian network of two prior distributions (A and B) and one posterior distribution (C|A,B). How, in scipy, would I find the most likely value of C?

Secondarily, how would I calculate the confidence level for that value? I'd define the confidence level to be equal to the probability that the actual value of C is equal or greater than the given value.

To be more concrete, A and B are cumulative probability functions (cdf) of x. Given a particular a, A(a), gives the probability that the actual value of A is less than a.

Similarly, C is a function of a,b,c and returns the probability that the actual value of C is less than c, given particular values of A and B.

Comment: This is not a programming question---I'd suggest http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or a math forum.

Comment: While the subject of my program is math, I still believe this is a programming problem, since my chief trouble is (was) the implementation. If I had trouble writing a program about cars, I hope you wouldn't send me to cars.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be working with the probability density functions (PDF) not the CDFs.  You obtain the PDF from the CDF just by differentiating it (do it numerically if the functions are tabulated).  Note that the way that you've specified it, taking the derivative of your 
`CDF(c | a, b)` with respect to `c` gives you the conditional probability density `p(c|a,b)`.

To obtain the marginal distribution for `c`, you'll need to integrate `a,b` out:

```
[b_min, b_max]=[-10.0, 10.0] # whatever the reasonable bound in b are
[a_min, a_max]=[-10.0,10.0] # whatever the reasonable bounds in a are

def pc_conditional( c, a,b ):
    ''' conditional probability density p(c|a,b)'''
    ...
def pa(a):
     ''' probability density p(a)'''
     ....
def pb(b):
    ''' probability density p(b)'''
   ...

def joint_distribution( c, a,b ):
    ''' joint distribution over all variables; p(c,a,b)=p(c|a,b)p(a)p(b) '''
    return pc_conditional(c,a,b)*pa(a)*pb(b)

def pca_marginal( c, a ):
     ''' distribution over c,a after integrating out b; p(c,a)=integrate[ p(c,a,b)db] '''
    def integrand( b ):
        return joint_distribution( c,a ,b)
    return scipy.integrate.quad( integrand, b_min, b_max)

def pc_marginal(c):
    def integrand(a):
         return pca_marginal( c, a )
    return scipy.integrate.quad( integrand, a_min, a_max )

# You can all pc_marginal(c) to obtain the (marginal) probability
# density value for the selected value of c.  You could use vectorize
# to allow for calling it with an array of values.
```

Now that you can compute the distribution `p(c)`, you can compute any statistical information you like.

Comment: I prefer to think about the cdf, since I can represent probabilities of discreet functions (with step functions and such), whereas the corresponding pdf has impulses on it, which I find hard to represent or work with.

Comment: To do what you want to do, i.e. marginalize out `a,b`, you need to work  with the pdfs.  If your variables are discrete, that makes life easier, since you just need to do sums (I inferred continuous variables since you used CDFs and they are typically only used for continuous variables).

Comment: Thanks Dave. In reality, A is the estimated mean, B the estimated variance, and C the normal distribution, conditioned on the variance and mean. The "reasonable bound" for the mean must be [-inf, inf]. Will this method continue to be valid?

Comment: Yes, assuming that your distributions on the mean/variance are well behaved (go to zero at infinity sufficiently fast).  `scipy.quad` can handle infinite bounds on the integration.